# How do I fix this: Error: /usr/local/Cellar is not writable? Why does chown returns "illegal username"?

Tags: node.js, macos, homebrew, chown

I was trying to install Nodejs using Homebrew (I'm using macOS Sierra 10.12.6) so I wrote in the terminal:

```
brew install node
```

and it returned:

```
Error: /usr/local/Cellar is not writable. You should change the
ownership and permissions of /usr/local/Cellar back to your
user account:
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar
```

Then I wrote:

```
 sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/Cellar
```

and it returned:

```
usage: chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] owner[:group] file ...
   chown [-fhv] [-R [-H | -L | -P]] :group file ...
```

After that I tried with:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(brew --prefix)/*
```

and it returned:

```
chown: /usr/local/Cellar: illegal user name
```

May I have your help please? (Note: the username is the right one)

Comment: what does `whoami` print?

Comment: My username, the same one that I used in the command

Comment: I also added my OS version in the question

Comment: Those `chown` errors look like it's not getting the correct name from `$(whoami)`. Try using your username explicitly (i.e. `sudo chown -R yourUserNameHere /usr/local/Cellar`).

Comment: Already did it. I think the problem is that something about chown changed in Sierra

Comment: I'm pretty sure `chown` hasn't changed, and the usage message says it hasn't. The error messages suggest that it isn't getting your username (the last one suggests it's mistaking `/usr/local/Cellar` for the username), so something weird is happening. Either there's something strange about your username, or it's running a wrapper around `chown` that's messing things up, or... something I'm not going to think of without more information.

Comment: I tried to run the command in the way that I wrote it, without changing (whoami) and it seems to work.